# Finding a pair of values in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to find the row in an excel sheet where Column A and Column B fulfill my condition. Column C contains a value I want to get.
Example: I have following table (sorry seems like html tags for table don't work):

ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC 
A X 1
A Y 2

I want to get the row where column A is "A" and column B is "Y" and get the associated value from column C, which is "2" in this case.

I am already able to find the first entry for "A" which is in the first row. I am using excel.rangeFind. However, I want to know the row where column A is "A" and column B is "Y".

``

```
Excel.Range excelRangeA= workSheet.Columns["A:A"];
var rngFind = excelRangeA.Find("A");
string value= (excelApp.Cells[rngFind .Row, 3] as Excel.Range).Value;
```

``

My code gives me the value 1 from column C. But I want to have the value, where column A is "A" and column B is "Y", so I want to get the value "2" from column C..

Has anyone an idea? I think it might work with excel.range.findNext. This is what i tried so far:

```
Excel.Range excelRangeA= workSheet.Columns["A:A"];
var rngFind = excelRangeA.Find("A");

if (excelApp.Cells[rngFind.Row, 1].Offset[0, 1].Value == "Y")
        {
            string value= (excelApp.Cells[rngFind.Row, 3] as Excel.Range).Value;

            MessageBox.Show(value);
        }
        else
        {
            rngFindParam = excelRangeA.FindNext("A");
        }
```

Comment: First of all, you need to use `.Find("A")`, with quotes. Unless you have a variable `A` that holds the actual search text of course. Then `I tried to excel.range.findNext` - show us what you've tried, please. Finally: after using `.Find`, I would simply check the neighbouring cell using `Offset`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it with Offset. I think this could work. I edited my first post with what i tried with the FindNext.

Comment: You are mixing your variables and not using them properly. See my answer below and note how I use your rngFind range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Excel.Range excelRangeA = workSheet.Columns["A:A"];
var rngFind = excelRangeA.Find("A");
var found = false;
while (rngFind!=null || !found)
{
    if (rngFind.Offset[0, 1].Value == "Y")
    {
        string value = rngFind.Offset[0, 2].Value;
        found = true;
        MessageBox.Show(value);
    }
    else
    {
        rngFind = excelRangeA.FindNext(rngFind);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Only thing if found out is that you need rngFind = excelRangeA.FindNext(rngFind ) for the findNext. Then it searches for further matches. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Ah yes. Didn't test it... Thanks, I've updated the answer.